# helm3 installation fails with: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes and Helm. I have installed k3d and helm:
k3d version v1.7.0
k3s version v1.17.3-k3s1

```
helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

I do have a cluster created with 10 worker nodes. When I try to install stackstorm-ha on the cluster I see the following issues:

```
helm install stackstorm/stackstorm-ha --generate-name --debug
client.go:534: [debug] stackstorm-ha-1592860860-job-st2-apikey-load: Jobs active: 1, jobs failed: 0, jobs succeeded: 0
Error: failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
helm.go:84: [debug] failed post-install: timed out waiting for the condition
njbbmacl2813:~ gangsh9$ kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

kubectl describe pods either shows :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From                             Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>           default-scheduler                Successfully assigned default/stackstorm-ha-1592857897-st2api-7f6c877b9c-dtcp5 to k3d-st2hatest-worker-5
  Warning  Failed     23m                 kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-5  Error: context deadline exceeded
  Normal   Pulling    17m (x5 over 37m)   kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-5  Pulling image "stackstorm/st2api:3.3dev"
  Normal   Pulled     17m (x5 over 28m)   kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-5  Successfully pulled image "stackstorm/st2api:3.3dev"
  Normal   Created    17m (x5 over 28m)   kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-5  Created container st2api
  Normal   Started    17m (x4 over 28m)   kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-5  Started container st2api
  Warning  BackOff    53s (x78 over 20m)  kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-5  Back-off restarting failed container
```

or

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                             Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>              default-scheduler                Successfully assigned default/stackstorm-ha-1592857897-st2timersengine-c847985d6-74h5k to k3d-st2hatest-worker-2
  Warning  Failed     6m23s                  kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-2  Failed to pull image "stackstorm/st2timersengine:3.3dev": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/stackstorm/st2timersengine:3.3dev": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/stackstorm/st2timersengine:3.3dev": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Astackstorm%2Fst2timersengine%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
  Warning  Failed     6m23s                  kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-2  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    6m22s                  kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-2  Back-off pulling image "stackstorm/st2timersengine:3.3dev"
  Warning  Failed     6m22s                  kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-2  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    6m10s (x2 over 6m37s)  kubelet, k3d-st2hatest-worker-2  Pulling image "stackstorm/st2timersengine:3.3dev"
```

Kind of stuck here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This totally looks like your nodes cannot reach https://docker.io (docker hub).

Comment: I just deployed this and pulling images works fine for me. This indicates potential network issue at your side. Do you use proxy/vpn? Where are you running your k3d cluster?

Comment: I disconnected office VPN and tried and still see the same error..K3d cluster is running locally on my laptop..

Comment: Also, when i try to pull the image using docker pull it works fine.

Comment: As a test can you try to deploy a single pod (busybox, nginx) in k3d but without helm and let us know the outputs? It could be that your local setup has not enough resources to run this. If you deploy stackstorm, all of its components have issue with pulling images or just some of them?

Comment: Followed the blog : https://medium.com/@yannalbou/k3d-k3s-k8s-perfect-match-for-dev-and-testing-896c8953acc0 and i could run the ngnix container on the k3d

Comment: This confirms that your cluster is running fine. How many resources you have available for the stackstorm deployment?

Answer (score 3):

The `TLS handshake timeout` error is very common when the machine that you are running your deployment on is running out of resources.  Alternative issue is caused by slow internet connection or some proxy settings but we ruled out that since you can pull and run docker images locally and deploy small nginx webserver in your cluster.

As you may notice in the `stackstorm` helm chart it installs a big amount of services/pods inside your cluster which can take up a lot of resources.

> It will install 2 replicas for each component of StackStorm
> microservices for redundancy, as well as backends like RabbitMQ HA,
> MongoDB HA Replicaset and etcd cluster that st2 replies on for MQ, DB
> and distributed coordination respectively.

I deployed `stackstorm` on both k3d and GKE but I had to use fast machines in order to deploy this quickly and successfully.

```
NAME: stackstorm
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Jun 29 15:25:52 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
Congratulations! You have just deployed StackStorm HA!
```